# Delay function removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout, owl-carousel

I've got a function for my Owl Carousel which is adding a class "turn-on" when current slider is visible, and removing when it's not.

```
function syncPosition(el){

  var current = this.currentItem;      

  this.owl.owlItems.removeClass('turn-on');

  setTimeout( function() {
  $(this).removeClass("turn-on");
  }, 2000);

  $(this.owl.owlItems[this.owl.currentItem]).addClass('turn-on');

  }
```

Now I need to add 2 second delay for removeClass. 
I've tried with set-timeout, delay but I am doing something wrong because it doesn't work.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGrGN/1060/)

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` in timeout is different than in syncPosition.
should be

```
function syncPosition(el){

  var current = this.currentItem;      

  this.owl.owlItems.removeClass('turn-on');
  var t = this;     

  setTimeout( function() {
     $(t).removeClass("turn-on");
  }, 2000);

  $(this.owl.owlItems[this.owl.currentItem]).addClass('turn-on');

  }
```

Comment: But it still doesn't work. What I want to do is to have the red line (progress bar) from my fiddle visible 2 seconds more at the end.